# What function can achieve the following?

Tags: functions

So I have some values which are computed linearly. But I want to stress the middle range more so I want the values to be "transformed" into something like this:

[image: the plot I want]

So basically, say for $x$ between $0$ and $100$, it should start steeper, $f(x) - x$ should be biggest in the middle at $50$ and cross $f(x) = x$ at $100$. After $100$ it should have a rather slow slope.

Note that the plot above is just a rough sketch, the real function should of course be smooth and have no saltus.

Can you show me a form of a function which has these attributes?

Comment: This is looks like a piecewise defined function.

Comment: Your sketch doesn't seem to "have the highest slope in the middle at 50". Its slope is highest right at 0. Are you sure you don't mean that $f(x)-x$ is highest at 50?

Comment: @HenningMakholm you are right, I meant $f(x)-x$, updated the question as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to meet the conditions you sketch, which can have quite different behavior for $x\gg 100$.

One natural approach, since you're concerned about the *difference* between $x$ and $f(x)$ reaching a maximum for a particular $x$, is to design this difference instead of $f$ itself. In that case we're looking for a $g$ such that

1. $g(0)=g(100)=0$,
2. $g(x)$ has a maximum at $x=50$, and
3. $g(x)$ never slopes downward so much that $f(x)=x+g(x)$ would have a downward slope (you don't say this explicitly, but it's implicit in your sketch).

The third condition means that we cannot use a simple parabola as $g$. But we can use a hyperbola instead: $g(x)=b-\sqrt{(x-50)^2+a}$ for appropriate constants $a$ and $b$. This works out to
$$ f(x) = x + \sqrt{2500+a} - \sqrt{(x-50)^2+a} $$
where the positive constant $a$ determines (indirectly) how much larger than $x$ $f(x)$ gets at $x=50$; you should select an $a$ that suits your application by trial and error.

This solution has the property that $f(x)$ will approach a finite limit for large $x$. If you want $f(x)$ to continue increasing with a nonzero slope (but smaller than 1), multiply $g$ by $(1-c)$ where $c$ is your desired limiting slope:
$$ f(x) = x + (1-c)\sqrt{2500+a} - (1-c)\sqrt{(x-50)^2+a} $$

Comment: Thank you for that answer! It provided the much needed approach to finding an appropriate function. What I came up with now is $f(x)=x+0.8*sqrt(5000)-0.8*sqrt((x−50)^2+2500)$, with the resulting plot here: http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427eijm756psb9

Comment: @Luksurious: You might consider adjusting your $a$ to $2400$ instead; then the constant term becomes an exact integer and it will be easier to avoid rounding errors at $0$ and $100$.

Answer (score 0):

Let f(x) = ax^3+bx^2

f(0) = 0

f(100) = 10^6a+10^4b = 100

f'(x) = 3ax^2+2bx

f''(x) = 6ax + 2b

f''(x) at x=50 must be equal to 0 for the highest slope

6ax+2b = 0

300a + 2b = 0

b = -150a

10^6*a - 10^*(-150) = 100

a = -1/5000

b = 15/500 = 3/100

Now let us define f(x) = ax+b

f(100)  =  100a +b =  100

f(200) = 200a + b = 130

a = .3

b= 70

Thus the function can be represented by piecewise functions such that

f(x)= (-1/5000)x^3+(3/100)x^2

for 0 < x < 100

f(x)= .3x+70

for 100 < x < 200

Thanks

Satish

Comment: Thanks for the effort. However, I just realize a mistake in my question, that at $x=50$ the function should not have the highest slope but $f(x)-x$ should be biggest, sorry!

Comment: Looking at the resulting function at http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e176lfieqja it would be pretty close if the point at $(50,50)$ would be at $(0,0)$ while stretching the part between $50$ and $100$ so that the point at $100$ remains the same. How would you modify it to achieve that?